# Roles.IsUserInRole always returns false. How do I return true?

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services

I have a WCF webservice in .Net 4.5, using C#.  I am trying to use PrincipalPermission for authorization but was always failing the authorization check.  So for debugging I switched to calling Roles.IsUserInRole("SystemAdministrator").  The Roles.IsUserInRole is always returning false.  The principal is set in my AuthorizationManager class:

```
        protected override bool CheckAccessCore(OperationContext operationContext)
    {
        ...

        if (! MembershipProvider.ValidateUser(credentials.UserName, credentials.Password))
        {
            return false;
        }

        var user = MembershipProvider.GetUser(credentials.UserName, true);

        var claims = new List<Claim>().InjectInstanceClaims()
                                               .InjectUserClaims(user)
                                               .InjectAuthenticationClaims("CustomAuth");

        var roles = RolesProvider.GetRolesForUser(user.Name);
        foreach (var role in roles)
        {
            claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role));
        }
        var authenticatedUser = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "CustomAuth"));

        Thread.CurrentPrincipal = authenticatedUser;

        return user.IsApproved && ! user.IsLockedOut;

    }
```

And then in my AuthorizationPolicy I set the evaluationContext.Properties["Principal"] to the Thread.CurrentPrincipal.

```
public class AuthorizationPolicy : IAuthorizationPolicy
{
    public AuthorizationPolicy ()
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
    }

    public string Id { get; private set;
    }
    public bool Evaluate(EvaluationContext evaluationContext, ref object state)
    {
        evaluationContext.Properties["Principal"] = Thread.CurrentPrincipal;
        return true;
    }

    public ClaimSet Issuer
    {
        get { return ClaimSet.System; }
    }
}
```

When I get to my WCF method, I can verify in the debugger that I have the user that I created above and that it has the claim of ClaimTypes.Role / "SystemAdministrator" in the Identity.Claims, but my call to IsUserInRole is always false.

```
    public IEnumerable<Credentials> GetAllCredentials()
    {
        if (!Roles.IsUserInRole("SystemAdministrator"))
        {
            throw new HttpException(401, "Not authorized");
        }
        return CredentialData.GetAll();
    }
```

How do I get Roles.IsUserInRole to return true with a custom AuthorizationManager and custom AuthorizationPolicy?

Comment: Looks like I should be using CurrentPrincipal.IsInRole instead.

Comment: So the above works with CurrentPrincipal.IsInRole, and also when I remove that code and put in the attribute [PrincipalPermission....) for that role.